# How to split a Quantum Circuit on a barrier in Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, programming, circuit-construction, random-quantum-circuit, randomised-benchmarking

Let's say I have a `QuantumCircuit` with multiple `barrier`s as shown in the visual below:
[image: Quantum Circuit with Multiple Barriers]

How would I split up the `QuantumCircuit` on the `barrier`s into a list of 3 `QuantumCircuit`s in **Qiskit**?

NB: Not directly relevant to the question, but the circuit is a random Unitary circuit, as I'm doing randomised-benchmarking. The circuit is generated as shown in the [Qiskit Textbook: 5.3 Randomized Benchmarking](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-quantum-hardware/randomized-benchmarking.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a simple circuit, probably the easier way is to dump it as QASM and read it back.

```
def split_circuit_by_barrier(circuit):
    qasm = circuit.qasm()
    prelude = []
    circuits = [[]]
    for line in qasm.splitlines():
        if any([line.startswith(t) for t in ['OPENQASM', 'include', 'qreg', 'creg']]):
            prelude.append(line)
        elif line.startswith('barrier'):
            circuits.append([])
        else:
            circuits[-1].append(line)
    circuits_with_prelude = [prelude+circuit for circuit in circuits]
    for circuit_with_prelude in circuits_with_prelude:
        yield QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_str('\n'.join(circuit_with_prelude))
```

Taking your example:

```
for subcircuit in (split_circuit_by_barrier(circuit)):
    print(subcircuit)
```

```
                             ┌───┐ ┌───┐
   q_0: ─────────────────■───┤ H ├─┤ S ├─────
        ┌───┐┌───┐┌───┐┌─┴─┐┌┴───┴┐├───┤┌───┐
   q_1: ┤ H ├┤ H ├┤ S ├┤ X ├┤ SDG ├┤ H ├┤ X ├
        └───┘└───┘└───┘└───┘└─────┘└───┘└───┘
meas: 2/═════════════════════════════════════

        ┌─────┐┌───┐
   q_0: ┤ SDG ├┤ H ├───────■───────────────────
        └┬───┬┘├───┤┌───┐┌─┴─┐┌─────┐┌───┐┌───┐
   q_1: ─┤ X ├─┤ H ├┤ S ├┤ X ├┤ SDG ├┤ H ├┤ H ├
         └───┘ └───┘└───┘└───┘└─────┘└───┘└───┘
meas: 2/═══════════════════════════════════════

        ┌─┐
   q_0: ┤M├───
        └╥┘┌─┐
   q_1: ─╫─┤M├
         ║ └╥┘
meas: 2/═╩══╩═
         0  1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However when I run your function on my QuantumCircuit I get the following error: QasmError: "Expected an ID, received 'creg'"

Comment: Additionally I thought it might be the version so I upgraded from 0.19 to 0.20 and still the same issue.

Comment: additionally I think the reason I might be getting the above error is because I manually added the classical registers and measurements like so: qc.add_register(ClassicalRegister(2,'creg')); qc.barrier(); qc.measure([0,1], [0,1])

Comment: I see. This is a bug https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/5043 . The problem is the `creg` name. Change the name and I think it will work.

Comment: will try, thanks:)